# Cant get larger font working with this swipe effect

Tags: css, css-animations

I have found a CSS animation for a word swiping over from this code pen: [code](https://codepen.io/EricPorter/pen/JjPmOOb?editors=1100)

It works great! However, when I try to increase the font size to 70 the words start overlapping. I have played around with it but can't get it to work nicely.
How do I get this piece of code to work with a larger font size?
This is what I have now:

```
.wordCarousel {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #eee;
    div {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        height: 65px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        li {
            font-family: Serif;
            color: #eee;
            font-weight: 700;
            padding: 0 10px;
            height: 45px;
            margin-bottom: 45px;
            display: block;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes flip4 {
    0% {
        margin-top: -360px;
    }
    5% {
        margin-top: -270px;
    }
    25% {
        margin-top: -270px;
    }
    30% {
        margin-top: -180px;
    }
    50% {
        margin-top: -180px;
    }
    55% {
        margin-top: -90px;
    }
    75% {
        margin-top: -90px;
    }
    80% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    99.99% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -270px;
    }
}
```

The html is similar to this:

```
<h4 class="wordCarousel">
    <span>Word swipe animation: </span>
    <div>
        <!-- Use classes 2,3, or 4 to match the number of words -->
        <ul class="flip4">
            <li>Oh My!</li>
            <li>Swoosh</li>
            <li>Cool</li>
            <li>Squirrel</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the pixel values in your CSS animation are all in 90px-steps (-360px, -270, -180, -90, 0). So simply use larger steps in there, for example 120px:

```
@keyframes flip4 {
    0% {
        margin-top: -480px;
    }
    5% {
        margin-top: -360px;
    }
    25% {
        margin-top: -360px;
    }
    30% {
        margin-top: -240px;
    }
    50% {
        margin-top: -240px;
    }
    55% {
        margin-top: -120px;
    }
    75% {
        margin-top: -120px;
    }
    80% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    99.99% {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -480px;
    }
}
```

If that's not enough, try 150px-steps (-600, -450, -300, -150, 0, -600), or find out by trying which step value is best for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I tried to make it work but the words never fully show up in the right place.
Do you have any tips on how to make it work better?

Comment: Erase the `height` from the CSS rule for the `li` and adapt the `height` of the parent `div` – it should at least be the value of the used font-size, or a bit higher.

Answer (score 1):

It actually works fine on my screen. But 170px makes the words overlap on mine. I'll bet the issue is dependent on the screen size. Some screens work great with the font at 70 px, some don't.

You might try a relative length unit instead of px. See more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

You might look into **vw**. Go here and grab the middle bar separating the code from the result and move it back and forth to see the vw effect on the "Hello" font:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vw

Comment: Thanks for the help! 
I tried to make it work with VW but that only made the problem worse.
Do you have any tips on how to convert it to something that works?